# How to configure CloudWatch alarm based on the available RDS metric CPUUtilization of a Database engine using Cloud Development Kit (CDK)?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

I am trying to define and configure an alarm with an existing and AWS-defined CPUUtilization metric for the Aurora RDS database engine using the Cloud Development Kit (CDK) with Python.

The alarm monitors the CPU Utilization metric for the aurora database engine. If the CPUUtilization parameter is equal to or less than 5% for 120 seconds, it will give an alarm.

The CDK documentation describes how to provide custom metric with some dimensions but I would need to define an alarm with a given threshold for an existing metric type - CPUUtilization.

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is C# and missing required props, but would be a good starting place.

```
var aurora = new Amazon.CDK.AWS.RDS.DatabaseInstance(this, "aurora", new DatabaseInstanceProps()
{

});


var alarm = new Alarm(this, "my-alarm", new AlarmProps()
{
    ComparisonOperator = ComparisonOperator.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO_THRESHOLD,
    Metric = aurora.MetricCPUUtilization(new MetricOptions() 
    {
    }),
    Threshold = 5,
});
```